# Layout Issue - Button not adjusting

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout

**Update**

Now the button are of same size, but the the text in these button doesn't wrap completely and hides See the below screenshot for better understanding :-
[image]

i am updating the below XML code with the code at I have done at this point of time. If anyone wanna to know about the changes I made in this code for previous question, check answer section, I implemented that.

---

**Updated XML Code**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ans_a"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/alphabet_a"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ans_b"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ans_c"
                android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/alphabet_a"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/ans_d"
                android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Previous Question {Solved}**
I created a few buttons in which the text is downloaded from a server and then it is displayed on the button. I tried my best but I am not able to make them equal i.e.: whatever the size does the button with largest text takes, other button take the same shape. What it is happening now is, sometimes only upper button takes the shape, & sometimes only the lower ones. Can you help me setting this?

**Preview when blank**
[image]

**Text Loaded From Server but upper Button changes size and not lower**
[image]

**Text Loaded From Server but lower Button changes size and not upper**
[image]

Comment: your question really doesnt make much sense. plus the text looks the same to me... are you trying to change the font size of the text inside of the button dynaically?

Comment: Instead of android:layout_height="match_parent" try android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: No, actually the size of button is what, the issue was. But it has been solved - answer by ModularSynth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your inner LinearLayouts, this

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

has to be

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

So to make them change their heights according to their weights.

Comment: Glad to have contributed to your successful career! ;)

Comment: Hey, I noticed something that the button are now of same size, but some buttons are not adjusting automatically to the size so as to adjust full text. Please Help

Comment: What happens if you set the buttons to height `wrap_content`? I guess they will no longer fit the container's height. Therefore, I would either limit the text size or the number of displayed characters. Or both, in case one limitation is not enough.

Comment: If i set this to wrap_content, the the text is displayed completely but the size of the button agains gets a different height for upper and lower onces.

Comment: I can't apply limitation because what I am doing is a quiz and I have to show the full answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, being the text contents DIFFERENT, you will have different heights anyway. OR... you can **CHEAT**. Add many blank spaces to the shorter text (or give both a character padding - not a pixel padding, calculated on the biggest text you will use).

Comment: adding space might help me. Btw, i just tried to run my program on emulator on API 23 & API 19, and weight is not working there, it just goes like what wrap_content does, any idea whats going wrong ?
It is showing fine on real device with API 24

Comment: Then you might experience the same issue on an **emulated** Level 24 device.

Comment: I dont have the API 24 in emulator to test

Comment: ... Make or download one? Or do the inverse and test your app on a **physical** API 19 o 23 device?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by setting weight sum as 2 to the outer and inner Linear layouts, and also settings the layout_width as match parent in the buttons.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ans_a"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ans_b"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ans_c"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ans_d"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check the issue which is arising

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ans_a"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ans_b"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ans_c"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ans_d"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/play_page_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```